# Modules for Kotlin in Intellij

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I am looking for modules inside an intellij Project for Kotlin.
My structure is like that:

|- Project
|-- .idea
|-- src
|-- Project.iml

And i want to have a Module inside the project like:

|- Project
|-- Module1
|---Project.iml
|-- .idea
|-- src
|-- Project.iml

The module was created by right clicking on the project in the project structure view and creating a new module. There I couldnt find an option for Kotlin, only for java.
I tried Java, but I get the Error, that it can't find Kotlin functions like println(), understandable.
So are there Kotlin Submodules?
Kotlin code runs normally inside the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [known limitation](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-21915/Enable-New-module-functionality-for-new-project-wizard-for-Kotlin).

There is no way to add Kotlin modules at the moment.